# How to center text using css?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple paragraph  , I would like to center it like this

[image: demo]

Here is html

```
    <div class="col-6 info-left">
      <h1>Warentykowe Prezenty</h1>
      <span class="small-text">Od serce kafetrii</span>
      <p>
        Posłuchaj Serca Kafeterii i w Walentynki podaruj bliskiej osobie
        więcej miłosci ! Przygotowalismy zestawienie prezentowych
        bestsellerów dla niej, dla niego dla Was i... dla Ciebie - miłość
        nie jedno ma imię, zastanawiałes się już kogo obdarujesz w tym roku
      </p>
    </div>
```

Here is css

```
.info-left, .info-right{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
/* .banner-info{
      padding: 31px 0px 215px;
} */
.info-left > h1{
    font-size: 48px;
    font-family: "Open Sans Condensed";
    color: rgb(241, 107, 108);
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.2;
    text-align: center;
    text-indent: 2.65px;
}
.info-left p{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
    line-height: 1.5;
    text-align: left;
    width: 63%;
}
  .small-text{
    font-size: 21px;
    font-family: "Open Sans Condensed";
    color: rgb(241, 107, 108);
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.8;
    text-align: left;
    text-indent: 2.65px;
}
```

unfortunatelly I am getting this
[image]

I tried different combination but I could not get it done as I want

what do I need to change to get what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `text-align` in your `p` element to justify (to take the whole line) and also `text-align-last: center;` to center the last line.

```css
.info-left,
.info-right {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}


/* .banner-info{
      padding: 31px 0px 215px;
} */

.info-left>h1 {
  font-size: 48px;
  font-family: "Open Sans Condensed";
  color: rgb(241, 107, 108);
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-align: center;
  text-indent: 2.65px;
}

.info-left p {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
  line-height: 1.5;
  width: 63%;
  text-align: justify;
  text-align-last: center;
}

.small-text {
  font-size: 21px;
  font-family: "Open Sans Condensed";
  color: rgb(241, 107, 108);
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.8;
  text-align: left;
  text-indent: 2.65px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-6 info-left">
  <h1>Warentykowe Prezenty</h1>
  <span class="small-text">Od serce kafetrii</span>
  <p>
    Posłuchaj Serca Kafeterii i w Walentynki podaruj bliskiej osobie więcej miłosci ! Przygotowalismy zestawienie prezentowych bestsellerów dla niej, dla niego dla Was i... dla Ciebie - miłość nie jedno ma imię, zastanawiałes się już kogo obdarujesz w tym
    roku
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are specifically specifying `text-align:left` for the `p` element under class `.info-left`:

```
.info-left p{font-size:14px; ... text-align:left; ... width:63%;}
```

```css
.info-left, .info-right{display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;flex-direction:column;}

/* .banner-info{padding:31px 0px 215px;} */

.info-left > h1{font-size:48px;font-family:"Open Sans Condensed";color:rgb(241, 107, 108);font-weight:bold;line-height:1.2;text-align:center;text-indent:2.65px;}

.info-left p{font-size:14px;font-family:"Open Sans";color:rgb(100, 100, 100);line-height:1.5;width:63%;}

.small-text{font-size:21px;font-family:"Open Sans Condensed";color:rgb(241, 107, 108);font-weight:bold;line-height:1.8;text-align:left;text-indent:2.65px;}
```

```html
<div class="col-6 info-left">
    <h1>Warentykowe Prezenty</h1>
    <span class="small-text">Od serce kafetrii</span>
    <p>
        Posłuchaj Serca Kafeterii i w Walentynki podaruj bliskiej osobie
        więcej miłosci ! Przygotowalismy zestawienie prezentowych
        bestsellerów dla niej, dla niego dla Was i... dla Ciebie - miłość
        nie jedno ma imię, zastanawiałes się już kogo obdarujesz w tym roku
    </p>
</div>
```

Because you are already specifying:

```
display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;
```

For the entire DIV with class `info-left`, you don't need to specify anything for the `p` elements under class `.info-left`. But there is no problem doing that.

Comment: thanks, Italy gal answer works perfectly as I want using align-last, thanks for help though

Answer (score 0):

You are setting it to `text-align: left` in your CSS. Change to `text-align: center` in the `.info-left p` block.

Comment: AH so you basically wanted to both justify and center the paragraph. This is a great solution by @Itay Gal, though perhaps the original poster can rewrite the title of the question.